# Atualizar o loop da label sozinha C#

Tags: c#

Tenho uma aplicação Windows Form que dev gerar números aleatórios e quero que ela atualize uma label de texto sozinha, assim, gerando números em loop.

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```cs
var random = new Random();

for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  label8.Text = random.Next(0, 99999).ToString();
  Thread.Sleep(3);
}
```

Estou inserindo ele em `Public Form2()` da seguinte forma:

```cs
public Form2() {
  InitializeComponent();
  
  var random = new Random();
  
  for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    label8.Text = random.Next(0, 99999).ToString();
    Thread.Sleep(3);
  }
}
```

Ao iniciar a aplicação ele gera o numero aleatório na label mas não fica gerando em loop. Como posso fazer isso funcionar?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do jeito que está fazendo, está travando o Thread atual nesse loop até que ele seja terminado, e então ele irá mostrar apenas o último resultado gerado.

Basicamente ele irá esperar percorrer todo o loop antes de continuar a execução da aplicação. Você precisa trabalhar com Multi-threading neste caso.

De forma grosseira, você pode desativar `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` para ignorar as chamadas de Thread insafe no Windows Forms. O ideal é fazer com [Thread-Safe calls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls?view=netdesktop-6.0).

Fora do thread, você chama a propriedade a partir de onde estava. Poderá usar o [`TaskFactory`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory?view=net-6.0) para isso.

Além disso, não é ideal colocar métodos de renderização no construtor da classe. Associe ele para o evento [`Form.OnShow`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.onshown?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) como mostro no exemplo abaixo,

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

    // associa o evento
    this.OnShow += Form2_Show;
}

public Form2_Show(EventArgs e) {
    new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => {
         var random = new Random();
         for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
         {
             this.label8.Text = random.Next(0, 99999).ToString();
             Thread.Sleep(3);
         }
    })
}
```

Novamente, esse método é apenas uma "gambiarra" para reduzir o que você precisa fazer. Obviamente não é ideal fazer chamadas Thread-Insafe. Estude sobre isso nos links que coloquei acima para construir uma aplicação Windows Forms fluente.

Outra forma que poderá utilizar é um [`BackgroundWorker`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-6.0). Também poderá utilizar `Timer`. O último não cria um Thread dedicado ao que você quer fazer. O primeiro sim. Ambos requerem chamadas de tipo Thread-safe.